# Using oauth2 service (like facebook) to authorize my app access to third party app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I'm using facebook connect to authorize users on my site, but I also popup a third party service for the users.
This third party service is also using facebook connect to authorize its users.

I don't want each user to be forced to go through the authorization phase twice.
Is there a way I can ask the user to authorize the third party service when he log-in my service get some token and use it when I pop-up the third part service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook SDK's `getLoginStatus` method to determine if the user has already authorized your app and is currently logged in. If, user logs in to your site using FB, he will not have to log in again.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

So, the user just logs in once and has to authorize the app for the first time only. You can read more about this method [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/).